# Child div with width = 100% expands parent div with maxWidth

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

So I have a parent div with a max width of 80vw. This parent div contains, among other, a child div with its width set to 100%. The child div contains some text. So basically this:

```
<div style={{maxWidth: '80vw'}}>
  {/* Some other elements */}
  <div style={{width: '100%'}}>
    Hello world. This is just text.
    This text is just some placeholder.
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would assume would happen in this case is that the current width of the parent div would be defined by the width of the 'Some other elements', and that the child div automatically scales to 100% of this current width of the parent div.

What actually happens is that the child div scales to 100% of the parent div's max width, not its current width. **How do I make the child div scale to 100% of the *current width* of the parent div's width?**

Comment: Why is the style between `{{ ... }}`??

Comment: Inline javascript-styling :)

Comment: And what is the output html you get?